# Java Command Prompt Calculator - Homework

Tags: java, command-prompt

I need a Java program that acts as a calculator in the command prompt. I could come up with this, but I have to input the problem one at a time(put in "2", push enter, put in "+", push enter, put in "2", push enter) and I wanted to know if I could make it where I can just put in "2+2" instead. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class memCalc
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String op;
        int numberOne, numberTwo, result = 0;
        numberOne = input.nextInt();
        op = input.next();
        numberTwo = input.nextInt();
        if (op.equals("+"))
        {
            result = numberOne + numberTwo;
            System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
        }
        else if (op.equals("-"))
        {
            result = numberOne - numberTwo;
            System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
        }
        else if (op.equals("*")) 
        {
            result = numberOne * numberTwo;
            System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
        }
        else if (op.equals("/"))
        {
            result = numberOne / numberTwo;
            System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this question necessarily deserves a down vote, just more explaining. You've stated what you are trying to achieve and you posted some code which I assume you want to modify so it matches. With that being said, have you at least tried anything? All that is really required here is some simple parsing.

Comment: @JoshM I don't really know what to try. Even someone telling me what I need to research would be helpful :)

Comment: Just try something that makes sense to you. Do some experimenting. Prompt the user to enter an expression and then invoke `Scanner#nextLine()` and `String#split(String)` it with a delimiter of a space. `split[0]` will be the first number, `split[1]` will be the operation, and `split[2]` will be the second number.

Comment: @JoshM Thanks! I'll mess around with this and then we'll see if I'm back!

Comment: If you want to get one line string at a time, try input.nextLine(). You'd better see API document for Scanner to see what kind of values Scanner support to read using next* methods, such as nextInt(), nextLine() etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution... but it works. Basically I just put the whole thing the user typed into a String, then find the location of the operator, then I find the 2 numbers using the location of the operation and put them into a int. After that, I used substring to put the operator into a String. Then, it is just what you got.

This is not the best code... but hop this helps

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String equation = input.nextLine();
    int opLocation = equation.indexOf("+");
    if(opLocation == -1)
    {
        opLocation = equation.indexOf("-");
    }
    if(opLocation == -1)
    {
        opLocation = equation.indexOf("*");
    }
    if(opLocation == -1)
    {
        opLocation = equation.indexOf("/");
    }
    String number = equation.substring(0,opLocation);
    int numberOne = Integer.parseInt(number);
    number = equation.substring(opLocation + 1);
    int numberTwo = Integer.parseInt(number);
    String op = equation.substring(opLocation,opLocation+1);
    int result;
    if (op.equals("+"))
    {
        result = numberOne + numberTwo;
        System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
    }
    else if (op.equals("-"))
    {
        result = numberOne - numberTwo;
        System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
    }
    else if (op.equals("*")) 
    {
        result = numberOne * numberTwo;
        System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
    }
    else if (op.equals("/"))
    {
        result = numberOne / numberTwo;
        System.out.print("The answer is: " + result + " .\n");
    }
}
```